# Laravel 5 how to get route action name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the current route action, but I'm not sure how to go about it. In Laravel 4 I was using `Route::currentRouteAction()` but now it's a bit different.

I'm trying to do `Route::getActionName()` in my controller but it keeps giving me method not found.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Route;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        echo 'getIndex';
        echo Route::getActionName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the method is removed because routes will be created with annotations in L5.

Comment: @arjan The default in L5 is now the normal routes, the same as L4. Annotations are now optional in L5.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you should be using Method or Constructor injection. This will do what you want:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(Route $route)
    {
        echo 'getIndex';
        echo $route->getActionName();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, great, one more question, how to do this in middleware. For instance I want to auto set the "view" in my layout based on the route. I tried doing the same thing there in the `handle` and `__construct` method but it's not working.  `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $methods ]] in class Illuminate\Routing\Route`

Comment: This is WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY too automagical to be comfortable with. I like to KNOW EXACTLY what's happening.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski - Method injection is a standard way Laravel 5 works. Nothing automagical about it - just standard dependency injection.

Answer (score 27):

To get action name, you need to use:

```
echo Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
```

and not

```
echo Route::getActionName();
```

Comment: For me the result is `App\Http\Controllers\AdsController@create`, so it is not only action name. Is it possible to get only it?

Comment: getting error - Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Route' not found

Answer (score 11):

To get only the method name you can use ...

```
$request->route()->getActionMethod()
```

or with a facade ...

```
Route::getActionMethod()
```

Comment: how to use it in Lumen 8.x in middleware? Kindly suggest Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

To get action name only (without controller name):

```
list(, $action) = explode('@', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName());
```

Comment: how to use it in Lumen 8.x in middleware? Kindly suggest Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

Use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

If you want to get the alias of the route, you can use:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName()
```

Comment: Not working for me. I am using Laravel 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get the route action name on Middleware i do that:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class HasAccess {

    protected $router;

    public function __construct(User $user, Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $action_name = $this->router->getRoutes()->match($request)->getActionName();
        //$action_name will have as value 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@showWelcome'
        //Now you can do what you want whit the action name 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

EDIT: You will don't get the routes which are protected by this middleware :(

Answer (score 2):

To get only action name in Laravel 5.4

`explode('@', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName())[1]`

Can't find any better way, to use in view, in one line...

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.5 if you just want the method/action name i.e. show, edit, custom-method etc... do this

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod()
```

No need to use explode or list to get the actual method to be called. Thanks to Laravel who thought of this.

Comment: It works, but how to get controller name also, please suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.1 use:

```
$route = new Illuminate\Routing\Route();
$route->getActionName(); // Returns App\Http\Controllers\MyController@myAction
$route->getAction(); // Array with full controller info
```

There are lots of useful methods in this class. Just check the code for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You may use to get the controller details form the request itself

```
$request->route()->getAction()
```

Comment: This seems to not work in Lumen 5.7. Can anyone tell me why that is? It seems that  Illuminate/Routing/Router does not get installed when you install laravel/lumen? Am I wrong in saying this? I want to get the right controller version but I can't change action since $request-route() is an array and there is not member function in that array that calls getAction() method.

Answer (score 1):

This working perfectly good for me.

```
$request->route()->getActionMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->route()->getAction()['prefix'] // return 'api'
```

Answer (score 0):

### I used this, and it is working in view.

A few options.

Pass variables to the view from your controller.
Set a global view variable
use view composer.
You need to choose one of these depending on your use case.

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction();
Route::currentRouteAction();
Route::currentRouteName();
```