# How to get action name in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't have any idea how to just get action name in Laravel 5.1?? It's giving complete route instead of just action name.

```
public function saveuserstat(Route $route)
{
    echo $route->getActionName();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 how to get route action name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840278/laravel-5-how-to-get-route-action-name)

Comment: I am asking action name only not complete route @limonte

Comment: take a look at my answer below :)

Comment: If all you want is the method name (aka `saveuserstat`), then you could simply use PHP's `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: @AliRaza if you're happy with my answer you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

As `getActionName()` returns complete route with controller name and action name, you should do this trick to get action name only:

```
list(, $action) = explode('@', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName());
```