# Laravel : How to check dynamic url using Request::path()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I was trying to show a search box based on url means for specific route it will show the search box otherwise it won't show. for that i used `Request::path()` . But the problem is for some route it doesn't work.
Suppose i have two routes, such as

```
Route::get('products','abcontroller@index');
Route::get('product/{name}','abcontroller@searchProduct');
```

now if i used the following code:

```
@if(Request::path() == 'products' || Request::path() == 'product/{name}')
  // something print
@endif
```

For the `products` route i could see the search Box but for `product/{name}` I couldn't .. How do i solve the issue?

Comment: Have you checked `Request::path()` value?

Comment: You can get a proper solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26840278/2679536)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Route::get('products',['as' => 'product.index', 'uses' => 'abcontroller@index']);
Route::get('product/{name}',['as' => 'product.name', 'uses' => 'abcontroller@searchProduct']);
```

use

```
@if(Route::is('product.*')
// something print
@endif
```

Hope can help you

Answer (score 2):

Much better idea would be to handle this via controller itself, by passing a value to the view. That will make for better encapsulation, because your layout won't need to know about any routes.

If you display search bar by default, go with **not** showing it if a value is present. If it's only shown for some pages, show it only when the value is actually present.

Comment: I used it in view directly through `Ruquest::url()`

Comment: In my opinion, URL should not be used as the identifier of any page. Try to use `@isset($showSearchBox)` in your view to check if it exists and pass `showSearchBox` with `true` value (or anything) in any controller action that is supposed to show the view with search box. Or, like I said before, make it `$hideSearchBox` if you usually show it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Route::get('product/{name}',
    ['as' => 'product.name', 'uses' => 'abcontroller@searchProduct']);
@if(Route::is('product/*')
 //your Code
@endif
```