# How to get the action from a given laravel route name?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I have route defined as:

```
Route::name('foo')->get('/foo', 'FooController@index');
```

I know that given the route name, I can get the URL:

```
route('foo'); // "http://localhost/foo"
```

I also know given the action, I can get the same URL:

```
action('FooController@index'); // "http://localhost/foo"
```

But how can I get the action given the route name?

e.g. maybe something like this:

```
getActionFromRouteName('foo'); // "FooController@index"
```

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840278/laravel-5-how-to-get-route-action-name#26841923)??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841923/4668162

Comment: @kerbholz that only works if you're on the current route. I need the action name for a different route, for which I only have the name.

Comment: @Onix that only works if you're on the current route. I need the action name for a different route, for which I only have the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Route Facade.

```
\Route::getRoutes()->getByName('test')->getActionName() 
// "App\Http\Controllers\TestController@index"
```

or the array with the whole action data:

```
\Route::getRoutes()->getByName('test')->getAction()

/*
[
 "middleware" => "web",
 "as" => "test",
 "uses" => "App\Http\Controllers\TestController@index",
 "controller" => "App\Http\Controllers\TestController@index",
 "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers",
 "prefix" => null,
 "where" => [],
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the route from the request and call `getActionName()`, something like:

```
public function someFunction(Request $request)
{
    $request->route()->getActionName();
}
```

Comment: That's only when on the current route. I need to find the action given only the route name.