# How to get the given route's method in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a route that is named `editUser`

when I try the following code:

```
return route('putUser');
```

It returns me the `url` of the given route

now I want to check what method is used for that route,

for example, It's a GET method or POST or anything else

what should I do?

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` from terminal. There you will find all of the routes with details.

Comment: @RashedHasan Please read my question again, then answer. thanks by the way

Comment: Is this something like what you're trying to find? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840278/laravel-5-how-to-get-route-action-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the methods defined on a named route by accessing the `RouteCollection`

```
$route = Route::getRoutes()->getByName('putUser');

$methods = $route->methods();
```