# Return callback based on route name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I searched the internet a lot, but couldn't find a solution.

I need to return the `callback` registered on a route, based on the route name.

---

**Example**

My routes/api.php:

```php
Route::get('test', 'TestController@test')->name('test');
```

That is, based on the example above, I want to capture the string `TestController@test`, stating that the route is 'test'.

It is possible?

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getActionName()` or `getAction('controller')` on a Route instance to get this information. You will get a FQCN. To get just the last part you can use `class_basename()`:

```
$route = Route::getRoutes()->getByName('test');

$action = $route->getActionName();
// 'App\Http\Controllers\TestController@test'

$basename = class_basename($action); 
// 'TestController@test'

// all together now
class_basename(Route::getRoutes()->getByName('test')->getActionName());
```

Comment: Found it 10 minutes before I do :D

Comment: hehe, still had it in mind from a previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356764/how-to-get-the-given-routes-method-in-laravel-5-8/58358051#58358051   :p

Comment: So this should be a duplicate :p

Comment: nah, they wanted the route method in the other one, this wants the action

Comment: Okay! fair enough

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get just the `TestController@test` you may do so like this

```php
substr(strrchr(Route::getRoutes()->getByName('test')->action['uses'], '\\'), 1);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)